# International master programm in Physic at university of Rostock

Tags: masters, germany

I am a physic student from Jordan, few days ago i got an admission to do my master in physics at university of Rostock, Germany.

Am I able to get a PhD position from other university when I finish my master study, i.e., will other German universities recognize my Master degree from Rostock university?

Answer (score 4):

A master's degree from a German *Universität* (University) or *Technische Hochschule* (Institute of Technology) is directly recognized by other universities in Germany (and usually by most other universities around the world). The same cannot be said for a *Fachhochschule* (FH). Rostock is officially a university, so that shouldn't be a major concern.